# How to create/edit/remove a group in Empathy

Tags: empathy

In 12.04 with Empathy 3.4.2.3 I can't seem to find the options for adding, removing or even editing a group. Are there still there or moved where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first i also only found how to remove groups:
You can right click on a group, the remove option shows up.

Now to add or edit a group, you need to right click on a contact, click on Edit.
An 'Edit Contact Information' screen shows up. There you can add new groups and edit existing ones.[image: screenshot]

Comment: To edit a group it does not work. At least trying to do a renaming. But yes your answer satisfies me. Empathy went from Video call, Desktop sharing and intuitive windows to "Where did everything go".

Comment: Yeah it used to be easier to work with it. Now it's just too simple.